# Webdriver Expected condition failed: waiting for element to no longer be visiblr

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a method which waits for a css (Modal) locator to not be visible on screen, on some of my builds I get the following failed message

> Expected condition failed: waiting for element to no longer be
>   visible: By.cssSelector: .modal-body (tried for 6 second(s) with 500
>   MILLISECONDS interval)
>       Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>       System info: host: 'DEV007', ip: '172.16.2.192', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_131'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591
>   (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),
>   userDataDir=C:\Users\GI\AppData\Local\Temp\2\scoped_dir7780_13017},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
>       Session ID: eb353964f7b9bd515e527a795a111bc3

My method:

```
public boolean waitUntilModalDisapears() {
    return this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".modal-body")));
}
```

Comment: Based on the stacktrace, I'm suspecting you are using the FluentWait implementation of the Wait interface. 

I would suggest you review your locator `".modal-body"`. It is possible that your locator would point to another element in your page and you're not waiting for the correct element to be invisible.

Answer (score 2):

Loading web elements in your page will be different each time you run your code so you should increase the wait time in your web driver wait and try running your code more than once to be sure your driver have waited enough time for the element to be loaded

try below :

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".modal-body")));
```

Comment: To add to this answer, the original poster's version attempts to execute the wait statement from whatever class it is in (this.wait....)  As shown in mohamed's example, you need to define the driver from which you are checking for the visibility of the element.  I'm not sure why the original poster's code, as shown, would even compile.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in this method and you use it right.
The code of this method (on C#) is:

```
return (Func<IWebDriver, bool>) (driver =>
{
try
{
  return !driver.FindElement(locator).Displayed;
}
catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
{
  return true;
}
catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex)
{
  return true;
}
});
```

So probably your element was visible indeed. Try to increase your timeout and maybe to make screenshots on failure to be able to view real data and to know if the element is visible or not indeed.